# Searching for multiple keywords in excel

Tags: excel

I have course listings with detailed description. I have 25 keywords in order to filter particular type of course. I want to count the number of courses with the description containing more than 3 keywords. Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: There is probably someone that can help you.  But you need to edit your question to provide sufficient detail as to what you need, what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.  Before you do that, it may be helpful to read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

One way...

Say course descriptions are in column A with heading in A1 and descriptions below in A2, A3, etc. Then, next to the header in following columns, we'll assume C and on to the right here, type in the keywords. Then:

```
//copy these down and to the right
In cell C2: =IFERROR(IF(FIND(C$1,$A2)>0,1,0),0)
```

Now of these cells under C2 and on to the right will have a 1 if the keyword matches the heading above that cell, a 0 if not. Then, just sum the columns in row be:

```
// copy these down
In cell B2: =if(SUM(C2:AD2)>2,1,0)
```

This column B will now show a 1 beside each course with 3 occurrences or more, a 0 for any with less. Now, just sum this column B for the total number of courses:

```
=SUM(B:B)
```

Note, this counts occurrences of a string. Thus a search for "and" would return to in the entry "random and unusual." Just a warning...

Comment: Thank you. I used similar formula i.e =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Keywordstable,Description)))>3,"Yes","No")

Answer (score 0):

Fill the *Excel* spreadsheet as follows:

Row `1`:

`A1`: *Description*. Below there will be descriptions of your courses.

`B1`, `C1`, ... `Z1` (next 25 cells) - Keywords to find in descriptions.

`AA1`: Sum. Below will be numbers of keywords found in each description.

Column `1`:

`A2`, `A3`, ... - Course descriptions.

Row `2` - Formulas for course 1:

`B2`:   Insert formula: `IF(ISNUMBER(SEACH(B$1;$A2));1;0)`

Note `$` characters in the formula above: `B$1` - fixed column (1)
and `$A2` - fixed row. This is required to keep column / row fixed,
as the formula will be copied (description below).

Copy the above formula to cells `C2:Z2`.
This way you have in each cell either 1 if the keyword above
(in row 1) was found in course name (in column 1).

`AA2` (sum column): Insert formula: `SUM(B2:Z2)`. This way in column AA
you have the number of keywords (from row 1) found in
description (in column `A`).

Copy formulas from `A2:AA2` to each following row with description filled.

Assuming that you have 100 such course descriptions, you have
till now filled:

- Row `1` with header data.
- Rows `2` to `101` with descriptions (column `A`) and formulas
  (further columns).

Then, in cell `AA102` (below the last sum) enter formula:
`COUNTIF(AA2:AA101;">3")` - count cells containing value more than 3.
This is the result you are looking for.

If you have more or less course descriptions, change the above
formula (and its location) accordingly.

And the last remark: I used non-English version of *Excel* and then
"manually" translated my native function names into English.
So in case of function name errors try to figure out what actual function
name should be.